# C# modifying instance variables of a class in another form

Tags: c#

For a project of mine I am building the game of life in visual studio forms. The problem I am currently facing is that I am not sure where to initialize my class objects so that their values can be modified by other forms.

This is my base form class where I am displaying the board game and current stats of the players:

```
public partial class Life : Form
{
    public Game game;

    public Life()
    {
        game = new Game();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Life_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Txt_BlueMoney.Text = game.player1.money.ToString();
        Txt_RedMoney.Text = game.player2.money.ToString();
    }

    private void Btn_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StartGame sg = new StartGame();
        sg.Show();


    }
}
```

My Game class is just a class that contains instances of other classes:

```
public class Game
{
    public Board board;
    public BoardSpaceEvent boardEvent;
    public Player player1;
    public Player player2;

    public Game()
        : base()
    {
        board = new Board();
        boardEvent = new BoardSpaceEvent();
        player1 = new Player();
        player2 = new Player();
    }

}
```

and here is an example of one of the classes that Game initializes in case its of any importance:

```
public class Player : BoardSpaceEvent
{
    // might need to add getter and setter to access these variables
    public bool endOfTurn;
    public int currentSpace;
    public int numChildren;
    public int money;
    public int advanceSpaces;
    public List<int> playerLifeCards;
    public string career; // superstar, agent, teacher, athlete, salesperson, doctor, accountant, artist, police
    public int salary;
    public int taxes;
    public bool autoInsurance;
    public bool houseInsurance;

    public Player()
        : base()
    {
        endOfTurn = false; // might need to switch this
        currentSpace = 0;
        money = 10000; // will have to change this to whatever you start with
        numChildren = 0;
        advanceSpaces = 0; // make sure to pass this as reference
        playerLifeCards = new List<int> { };
        career = "";
        salary = 0;
        taxes = 0;
        autoInsurance = false;
        houseInsurance = false;
    }
}
```

now what I am trying to do is open another form in which the user must pick between two buttons, and each of these buttons will modify the classes instance variables. What is the best way to do this? Here is what I have so far (my comment shows what I want to do):

```
public partial class StartGame : Form
{
    public StartGame()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Btn_College_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You've chosen college");
        // this is where I want to update a players money variable in the Player class
        this.Close();
    }

    private void Btn_Job_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You've chosen job");
    }
}
```

I have tried passing as reference and it did not work. Maybe I did it wrong though. I also tried inheriting from the main form, but the problem with that is the background is also inherited. I have looked into using static instances, but isn't this bad practice? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please don't spam language tags.

Comment: "I have tried passing as reference and it did not work." I don't see any code where you try to pass the reference. What exactly went wrong? Did your compiler cook a soup instead or code execution ?=! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Give the class `StartGame` a second constructor which can take a `Game` object as parameter and a local variable of type `Game localGame;`.

Then you can pass the `public Game game;` from the class `Life` when you open the `StartGame` Form:

```
private void Btn_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StartGame sg = new StartGame(game);
    sg.Show();
}
```

Simply assign the passed parameter in the `StartGame` constructor to the local variable and you will be able to use it in your `Btn_College_Click` method.

Hope this helps. If it is not clear drop me a comment

EDIT:

> I also tried inheriting from the main form, but the problem with that is the background is also inherited.

Even if inheritance would be possible it would not solve your problem. Each child would have it`s own personal instance of`Game` which is different from the object that the parent has. So changing the childs object would not influence the object of the parent.

Imagine your child inherits your hair colour. Now if you colour the hair of your child to a different on what will happen to your hair ?=!

Answer (score 0):

This worked when I just tried it:

```
public partial class Life : Form
{
    private int _money;

    public void AddMoney(int amount)
    {
        _money += amount;
        label1.Text = _money.ToString();
    }

    public Life()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var startGame = new StartGame(this);
        startGame.Show();
    }
}

public partial class StartGame : Form
{
    private readonly Life _life;

    public StartGame(Life life)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _life = life;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        _life.AddMoney(5);
    }
}
```